# How do you remove all the lines between two html tags using sed (or similar)?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
< ... stuff ... ></HEAD>
< ... stuff ... >
</HTML>
```

I'm trying to remove everything between, and including, the HEAD tags, but can't seem to get it to work.

I thought

```
sed -i -e 's/<HEAD>.*<\/HEAD>//g' file.HTML
```

should work, but it doesn't remove anything.

```
sed -i -e '/<HEAD>/,/<\/HEAD>/d' file.HTML
```

doesn't do anything either.  No errors, just nothing.

Is there something wrong with my input file, or is there a different way to go about it?

Comment: `sed -ie '/<HEAD>/,/<\/HEAD>/d' filename` ?

Comment: Right, that was assumed, I'll edit the post

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/jw55yK

Comment: Just worked for me, too... I wonder if it was one of the options I was forgetting.  Damn it.

Comment: No need for the `-e`, since there are only one expression: `sed -i '/<HEAD>/,/<\/HEAD>/d' file`

Comment: I hope that the tags `</HEAD>` and `<BODY>` are on different lines. When you do not want to lose your BODY you need to insert a newline to `</HEAD>` before removing it.

Comment: obligatory caution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552

Answer (score 13):

Delete all lines between tags leaving tags:

```
sed '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/{//!d}' input.txt
```

Delete all lines between tags including tags:

```
sed '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/d' input.txt
```

To change in place use `sed -i ...`. To change in place while backing up original `sed -i.bak ...` which will save the original as `input.txt.bak`.