# Remove Matched Nested Element Tag from KML File

Tags: xml, bash, unix, sed, kml

I am trying to remove the below section of code from a KML file, ideally using simple Bash/sed code.

I am familiar with removing XML tags using `sed` but, I'm not sure how to remove sub-tags matching  certain names.

To re-iterate, I need to match and then remove the entire "Overlay" `<Folder></Folder>` tag from the KML file.

**Attempted Bash Code for Parsing Desired Pattern Match:**

```
grep -B 1 "<name>Overlay</name>" -A 9
```

**KML Code:**

```
<Folder>
  <name>Overlay</name>
  <open>0</open>
  <Style>
    <ListStyle>
    <listItemType>check</listItemType>
    <bgColor>00ffffff</bgColor>
    <maxSnippetLines>2</maxSnippetLines>
    </ListStyle>
  </Style>
</Folder>
```

Comment: Are there multiple `<folder>` elements in your KML? What does the file look like after the removal?

Comment: Yes, there are three others

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The complete removal of `<Folder></Folder>`

Comment: It's still not clear: if there are multiple `<folder>` elements, do you want to remove them all or just those which have a child `<name>` element with a `Overlay` text? It's probably better if you edit your question and show a sample KML file before and after the removal.

Comment: Can you use xmlstarlet?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530441/how-do-you-remove-all-the-lines-between-two-html-tags-using-sed-or-similar

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<Folder>/{:a;N;/<\/Folder>/!ba;/<name>Overlay<\/name>/d}' file
```

Gather up lines in the range from `<Folder>` to `</Folder>` and if the collection contains `<name>Overlay</name>` delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting one line `gawk` (normal `awk` in most Linux machines) script:

```
  gawk '/<Folder>/,/<\/Folder>/{next}1' input.kml
```

Answer (score 0):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used for your task.

It is a YAML processor and can also deal with XML.
The syntax is similar to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

As far as I have understood you correctly, you want to delete all  elements including it's child data,
that have as child element `<name> = 'Overlay'`.
The following code does this regardless of the nesting depth.

`NAME=Overlay yq --input-format xml --output-format xml e 'del(.. | select(type == "!!map") | select(.name == env(NAME)))' $INPUTFILE`

**Input**

```xml
<root>
  <Folder>
    <name>Data 1</name>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
    <name>Overlay</name>
    <open>0</open>
    <Style>
      <ListStyle>
      <listItemType>check</listItemType>
      <bgColor>00ffffff</bgColor>
      <maxSnippetLines>2</maxSnippetLines>
      </ListStyle>
    </Style>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
    <name>Data 2</name>
  </Folder>
</root>
```

**Output**

```xml
<root>
  <Folder>
    <name>Data 1</name>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
    <name>Data 2</name>
  </Folder>
</root>
```